# Where to store files in an Android project to be accessed by the BufferedReader?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, bufferedreader

I have a file (more specifically a .txt file) that I need to access. I tried creating my own resources folder then accessing it with BufferedReader but got a null pointer error.

So question:

Where is the best way to store this file and still use BufferedReader to access it?

Comment: in your assets directory if you dont have one create it in the same hierarchy like your res directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the res/raw folder.

Then you can do something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStream(context.openRawResources(R.raw.<filename>)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For files which you need to pack with apk you can use Asset, take a look at [project structure docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects).

For files downloaded later, I recommend using external storage.

Comment: is it possible to store with Asset and then read it with BufferedReader?

Comment: Yes, you can use `open()` from AssetManager, which will open a stream for you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

**3 Ways to access a File in Android:**

1. from asset i.e **Raw folder** but your apk file size is large because file is located or expoted with your apk.
2. from **external storage** i.e sdcard  you need write permission to access from sdcard.
3. from **internet**  you need internet permission to access that file.

All the above 3 methods can utilize the BufferedReader, you need to chain the inputstream with BufferedReader to read specify bytes of data instead reading 1 byte per byte.

my snippet code :

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "vishnu.txt");
try {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi));
    String temp = myReader.readLine();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myReader.close();
    fi.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```